# Solving the recurrence relation $a_k=3a_{k-1}+4a_{k-2}$ with $a_0=1$, $a_1=2$

Tags: recurrence-relations

> Solve the recurrence relation $a_k=3a_{k-1}+4a_{k-2}$ with $a_0=1$, $a_1=2$ using characteristic equation.

These are the steps I used. Is my work correct?

[image: My work]

Comment: Yes, that's perfect.

Comment: Looks right. It is quite odd to work with $a_3$ and $a_4$ to find the constants. Probably should fix so you are using $a_0$ and  $a_1$.

Comment: It's fine, but the system of equations would be simpler if you substituted $n=0$ and $n=1$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086883/what-is-the-explicit-formula-of-the-sequence-with-a-1-1-a-2-2-and-a-n-3a-n?rq=1